# Integral in R^n formula

Tags: integration

Is there a simple formula for calculating the following integral:

$\displaystyle\int_{D} dx$,

where $D=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n | \ F(x)\leq 0\}$, knowing that $F:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is a smooth function?

Comment: I do not think so. Otherwise, by the Layer cake representation (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layer_cake_representation) you would "easily" compute any integral...